# sprite animation in openGL

Tags: android, sprites

I am facing problems on implementing sprite animation in openGL ES.
I've googled it and the only thing i am getting is the Tutorial implementing via Canvas.

I know the way but I am having problems in implementing it.

What I need : A sprite animation on collision detection.

What I did : Collision Detection function working properly.

PS : Everything is working fine but i want to implement the animation in OPENGL ONLY. Canvas won't work in my case.

------------------------ EDIT-----------------------

I now have a sprite sheet, say the one below having some certain co-ordinates, but from where will be the (u,v) co-ordinates start?
Should I consider my u,v co-ordinates from (0,0) or from (0,5) and in which pattern should i store them in my list..?
----> From Left to right
         OR
----> from top to bottom

Do i need to have a 2D array in my sprites class?
here is the image for a better understanding.

[image: Sprite sheet]
I am assuming that I have a NxN sprite sheet, where N = 3,4,5,6,....and so on.

.

.

```
class FragileSquare{

FloatBuffer fVertexBuffer, mTextureBuffer;

ByteBuffer mColorBuff;

ByteBuffer mIndexBuff;

int[] textures = new int[1];

public boolean beingHitFromBall = false;

int numberSprites = 49;

int columnInt = 7;      //number of columns as int

float columnFloat = 7.0f; //number of columns as float

float rowFloat = 7.0f;


public FragileSquare() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    float vertices [] = {-1.0f,1.0f,            //byte index 0
                         1.0f, 1.0f,            //byte index 1
                                    //byte index 2
                         -1.0f, -1.0f,
                         1.0f,-1.0f};           //byte index 3


    float textureCoord[] = {
                            0.0f,0.0f,
                            0.142f,0.0f,
                            0.0f,0.142f,
                            0.142f,0.142f           


    };


    byte indices[] = {0, 1, 2,
            1, 2, 3 };

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*2 * 4); // 4 vertices, 2 co-ordinates(x,y) 4 for converting in float
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    fVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    fVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    fVertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 4);
    byteBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer =  byteBuffer2.asFloatBuffer();
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoord);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0);

}



public void draw(GL10 gl){


    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(1,GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fVertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int idx = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*4))/200);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE); 
    gl.glTranslatef((idx%columnInt)/columnFloat, (idx/columnInt)/rowFloat, 0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //4
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer); //5
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); //7
    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

public void loadFragileTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

}

Comment: Sprite animation and collision detection have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: What kind of animation are you wanting? Skeletal, sprite sheet, something else?

Comment: @GameDev-er I have a sprite sheet.

Comment: @Mr.Beast I know they have nothing to do with each other. My aim to achieve sprite animation after collision. Till now i am able to achieve collision detection. But as far as sprite animation is concerned.. i am unable to do it.

PS : i am a newbie to openGL ES and here too.. so sorry for any of my comments, if any.

Comment: @Sid Why do you have x/y mixed up? :( X is the horizontal axis. (I know it isn't inherently but it's a convention that one shouldn't go against)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Those are the position of x-y coordinates. When you open any image in ms-paint and where ever you move your mouse pointer, it gives the position of x,y.
So i was talking in that respect.

Comment: Once you load it into a texture, the coordinates become normalized from (0,1) on both axes.  [If you're using OpenGL, 0,0 is the lower left corner of the texture](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/opengl-vs-direct3d-texturing/).  (D3D has 0,0 at the _top_ left).  You just need to store the lower left corner and _width_/_height_ of each frame of the sprite.  You don't need a 2d array, you need a 1D array of `struct SpriteFrame{ float uStartLL,vStartLL,uWidth,vHeight ; }` (LL stands for lower left, not [Lindsay Lohan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsay_Lohan))

Comment: thanks for the comment @bobobobo but i am not using any engine. I am using only openGL ES and with java as the background.

Comment: @Sid Hi Sid Hope you have done with this animation  I am trying to achive a sprite sheet animation with Open gl es , I tried with your code too But it render nothing to me. It will be very helpfull if you can give me a sample code , Advance thanks

Comment: @RenjithKN Hi Renjith, May i know how many sprites are you using? You may post your draw method if you have made one and the renderer class too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a code snippet I'm using in my Android application.

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);    //edit the texture matrix
gl.glTranslatef(u, v, 0);            //translate the uv space (you can also rotate, scale, ...)
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  //go back to the modelview matrix
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, getTexture());
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);           //map the texture on the triangles
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, getTextureBuffer()); //load texture coordinates
```

The trick here is to use glMatrixMode followed by glTranslatef.
That will allow you to translate the uv space.

uv coordinates range from (0,0) to (1,1)

Let's suppose you have a squared texture with 4 frames and you want to texturize a quad.
I will use the following coordinates to define frames in uv space (the choice is up to you)

1st (0, 0) (0.5, 0.5)

2nd (0.5, 0) (1, 0.5)

3rd (0, 0.5) (0.5, 1)

4th (0.5, 0.5) (1, 1)

With glTexCoordPointer you should map the 1st frame on your quad then when you want to show the 2nd frame you call glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0), glTranslatef(0, 0.5, 0) for the 3rd and glTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, 0) for the 4th.

The code above is tested and work very well, I hope the example is clear enough.

---

EDIT:

at the end of your draw function you should reset your texture matrix whit this code.

```
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

---

ok, let's take 5 rows and 4 columns as an example.
There are max 20 sprites in your spriteset so use
    int idx = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()%200*number_of_sprites)))/200);

idx now go from 0 to number_of_sprites-1 (can be < 20 if you have for example 5 rows, 4 columns but only 18 sprite) changing it's value every 200ms.
Assuming you have your sprite from left to right and from top to bottom than you can find your frame coordinate in uv space doing this.

```
int c = 4;      //number of columns as int
float cf = 4.f; //number of columns as float
float rf = 5.f; //number of rows as float
gl.glTranslatef((idx%c)/cf, (idx/c)/rf, 0);
```

when you do idx%c you find your column index, the results is always between 0 and c-1

idx%c is an integer, you need to scale it to a value between 0.0 and 1.0 so you divide by cf, cf is a float so there is an implicit cast here

idx/c is the same thing but for rows, idx and c are both integer so the result is still integer, and it's the row index, dividing by rf you get a value between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: I am using a triangle strip here. So will it work in this case?

Comment: One more thing.. in what manner should I store the co-ordinates?

----> 1D array
----> 2D array?

If 1D, then what all co-ordinates should i consider in the array?

Comment: @Sid Yes, it is the same thing, you just need to use the right uv mapping coordinates. Try to adapt my code snippet than if you need more help post your code

Comment: @Sid UV coordinates for glTexCoordPointer need to be stored in 1D array

Comment: I've added the code. i cant figure out what to do next.
I am assuming that I have a squared texture with 4 frames.

Comment: @Sid in your draw function after gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); paste those three lines
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
    gl.glTranslatef(u, v, 0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
You need to change the u and v values, for example if your 2nd frame start at (0.5, 0) call glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0) If you are unsure just experiment a bit ;)

Comment: that's okay, but i want an animation of sprites. The textures should keep on changing and repeating.

Comment: @Sid ok, assuming that you are now able to translate the uv space and that you are using 2x2 spriteset, put in draw `int idx = ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*4))/200);` this is untested but should give you a variable idx (index) that change value every 200ms from 0 to 3  This is your "current frame" index  Use that index to found your u and v frame coordinate and pass that to glTranslatef, example for 2x2 spriteset, `gl.glTranslatef((idx%2)/2, (idx/2)/2, 0);`

Comment: considering the above code, can i just add these lines in my program to make it work?

Comment: @Sid yes, put my code in your draw function and it should work. If it doesn't post the edited code and I will check it.

Comment: marco : i've tried your code. But the problem is that my background is also translating. So how to make it stop? I mean the background.

Comment: @Sid Are you using the same draw function for your sprite and your background? You should split your code in two classes, one that manage the background and another one that manage your sprite but for now you can surround the glTranslatef call with an if that check if you are drawing the sprite.

Comment: Marco : the code i've pasted is the final code.

Comment: @Sid post your updated code, I will check that

Comment: It is the updated code. Marco. The final one

Comment: Ok, where is `int idx = ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*4))/200);` ?? without that it can't work.. Also, you didn't tell me, are you using the same draw function for sprite and background?

Comment: I am using two different classes. MyGLSquare.java for the background.
and this one for a box. The code is same in both the classes except the three lines you gave me..

Hoe to make that as a different one.. as in "TO split your code in two classes, one that manage the background and another one that manage your sprite but for now you can surround the glTranslatef call with an if that check if you are drawing the sprite"

and use the different draw function for sprite or background?

Comment: @Sid see my edited answer, I have totally forgot that you need to reset the texture matrix. That's why your background was translated. Place that code snipped at the end of your draw function and it should work.

Comment: Marco :  nothing seems to happen now.

Comment: @Sid you need to put `int idx = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*4))/200);` INSIDE your draw function (1st line) not above in the class otherwise idx will not change it's value

Comment: Marco : done. But nothing happens.

Comment: Uhm.. it's strange.. Can you send me your project? I will try that.  By the way, no need to call `gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` twice.

Comment: Marco : Umm, actually its very large. Can you share your code snippet? I mean the sprite class and the render class and the other class that draw's your sprite sheets.?

Comment: @Sid found the problem, use `gl.glTranslatef((idx%2)/2.f, (idx/2)/2.f, 0);` instead of `gl.glTranslatef((idx%2)/2, (idx/2)/2, 0);`

Comment: The code works, but for a better understanding of my own self, what do these represent??
Elaborate please.

gl.glTranslatef((idx%2)/2.f, (idx/2)/2.f, 0);
"idx%2" ---> what does two represent here?
idx/2----?? what does two represent here?

what if i have a sprite sheet with textures contained in 5 rows and four columns?

Comment: I will edit the answer

Comment: Marco : this example is taking only one row with 4 columns only. and this program is running in background also. Why am i unable to stop the drawing even after the collision?

Comment: See my edited answer, you can set number_of_sprites=1 and rf=1.f and that will work for 4 columns 1 row spriteset. You can stop the animation preventing idx to change. for example, save the current idx in an old_idx variable. then replace `int idx = ...` with `int idx = collisionOccurred ? old_idx : ...` where ... is the same code

Comment: Marco : not working, it renders the same sprites all the time

Comment: Please update the code in your question

Comment: Sorry, just noticed an error, you need to set number_of_sprites = 4, not 1... Sorry for the mistake

Comment: i was setting it to 20. Marco.
Setting it to 4, i am still getting the same thing.

Comment: 20 if you are using a 5x4 sprite, 4 if you are using a 4x1 sprite by the way post the updated code

Comment: Marco, now i am using a 7x7 sprite, so it should be 49, Right?

Comment: that's right, c = 7; cf = 7.f; rf = 7.f; number_of_sprites = 49; if there are other problems please update your code :)

Comment: This is my edited code.

Comment: replace `int idx = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*4))/200);` with `int idx = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*numberSprites))/200);`

Comment: Marco : It is working but i am having some issues now. When I quit the activity, what i get is the same part from where i left and that activity is running in the background too, which is taking a lot of space.
Before animation, i was not having this problem.

Also, i want that my animation should stop when i reach the last frame.

Comment: for the 1st problem I don't know, it's working fine here, for the second one, you need to stop idx to roll back to 0 so a simple trick is this. Declare a variable `int oldIdx;` before `public FragileSquare()` then in the draw method do this: `int idx = oldIdx==(numberSprites-1) ? (numberSprites-1) : (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*numberSprites))/200); oldIdx = idx;`  By the way I think that we are going OT, the original question was answered, maybe you should close this one and open a new one if needed.

Comment: Marco : Sorry for bothering you, but the draw function is taking up random positions of sprites from the sheet. Don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It was working before right? How am I supposed to know why your code is not working now? Post the updated code and tell us what was changed and why. Also please post your spriteset if you can. And another thing, I don't think is fair to unaccept the answer just to post another OT question in the comments. Maybe I'm wrong but I think you should open a new question now.

Comment: I am so sorry Marco. let me just update the code.

Comment: Marco : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/sprite-animation-in-opengl-some-frames-are-being-skipped

Follow the link please.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Create texture containing all of your frames of your animation (side by side). Change the texture coordinates according to the frame you want to display.

Comment: Half of it has been done. But how should i achieve this part...... "Change the texture coordinates according to the frame you want to display."

PS : i am a newbie to openGL ES.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something called a **spritesheet**.

[image]

A spritesheet is just a single image with all the different "frames" that show the poses the character can take.  You select which "frame" of the sprite sheet to display either based on time (as for an explosion animation) or on player input (such as facing left, right, or drawing a gun)

The *easiest* way to do something like this is to have all related sprites be the same size (same width and height), and so getting the (u) coordinate of the 4th sprite from the left is just `(sprite_width*4.0 / sprite_sheet_width)`.

If you're trying to optimize and be space efficient, you can use a tool like [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to pack your sprites onto a single sheet.  TexturePacker also emits json or xml data that describes the xy locations of each of the sprites you load in.

Comment: I already have a sprite sheet. i know the method, its by shifting the co-ordinates. But my main question is "How to achieve this is openGL ES?" do you have any pseudo-code or a java code for this? The algorithm might work for me.

Comment: Write a `Sprite` class. Inside the `Sprite` class park a list of (u,v) pairs that describe the (u,v) coordinates of each "still" in the texture. You need 2 more variables to track time: one float to store "seconds per frame" (# seconds to spend on each animation frame), and another float called "clock", which stores the "current time" in the animation cycle.  When you go to draw, you must update the current time.  When "seconds per frame" is exceeded, you move onto the next frame of the animation, so that the animation moves on.

Comment: Okay, so the list containing (u,v) pairs will be a 2d array?

Comment: see the edited question please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [I_COLLIDE](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~geom/I_COLLIDE/index.html) with OpenGL.

Make each entity in the world a box, then check if each of the axises of the box are colliding with other entities.

With large amounts of entities to test for collisions you may want to check into an octree. You would simple divide the world into sectors, then only check for collision between objects in the same sectors.

Also utilize Bullet dynamics engine which is an open source collision detection and physics engine.

Comment: collision detection has already been achieved. My aim is to create a sprite animation.