# Sprite animation in openGL - Some frames are being skipped

Tags: android, sprites, opengl-es

Earlier, I was facing problems on implementing sprite animation in openGL ES.

Now its being sorted up. But the problem that i am facing now is that some of my frames are being skipped when a bullet(a circle) strikes on it.

What I need : A sprite animation should stop at the last frame without skipping any frame.

What I did : Collision Detection function and working properly.

PS : Everything is working fine but i want to implement the animation in OPENGL ONLY. Canvas won't work in my case.

------------------------ EDIT-----------------------

My sprite sheet. Consider the animation from Left to right and then from top to bottom

Here is an image for a better understanding.

My spritesheet ...
[image: Spritesheet]

class FragileSquare{

```
FloatBuffer fVertexBuffer, mTextureBuffer;
ByteBuffer mColorBuff;
ByteBuffer mIndexBuff;
int[] textures = new int[1];
public boolean beingHitFromBall = false;
int numberSprites = 20;
int columnInt = 4;      //number of columns as int
float columnFloat = 4.0f; //number of columns as float
float rowFloat = 5.0f;
int oldIdx;

public FragileSquare() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    float vertices [] = {-1.0f,1.0f,            //byte index 0
                         1.0f, 1.0f,            //byte index 1
                                    //byte index 2
                         -1.0f, -1.0f,
                         1.0f,-1.0f};           //byte index 3


    float textureCoord[] = {
                            0.0f,0.0f,
                            0.25f,0.0f,
                            0.0f,0.20f,
                            0.25f,0.20f         


    };


    byte indices[] = {0, 1, 2,
            1, 2, 3 };

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*2 * 4); // 4 vertices, 2 co-ordinates(x,y) 4 for converting in float
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    fVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    fVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    fVertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 4);
    byteBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer =  byteBuffer2.asFloatBuffer();
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoord);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0);

}



public void draw(GL10 gl){


    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(1,GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fVertexBuffer);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
       if(MyRender.flag2==1){ /** Collision has taken place*/
    int idx = oldIdx==(numberSprites-1) ? (numberSprites-1) : (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*numberSprites))/200); 
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE); 
    gl.glTranslatef((idx%columnInt)/columnFloat, (idx/columnInt)/rowFloat, 0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
    oldIdx = idx;
    }



    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);



    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //4
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer); //5
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); //7

    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);


    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

}

public void loadFragileTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);


    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Your sprite is 5x4 so `float rowFloat = 4.0f;` shoudn't be `float rowFloat = 5.0f;`? Also your textureCoord array is incorrect for that sprite, you should use 0.20f as v coordinate because it's 1.0/5;

Comment: Sorry Sorry, i forgot to edit that part. But its not working, i've updated the code.

Comment: The frames that are being skipped are the firsts?

Comment: they are being skipped in a random order. i just see the first row and the last row in this case and a few(2 or 3) frames from the left overs.

Comment: @MarcoMartinelli Hi, I need your help regarding this.. please have a look at the link. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46049/to-stop-spite-animation-scrolling-which-is-scrolling-along-with-the-background-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are getting the time from System.currentTimeMillis(). You don't know when your code will be executed so the initial value of idx is unknown.
You should save a timestamp when you detect a collision then replace System.currentTimeMillis() with (System.currentTimeMillis()-timestamp)

Pseudocode:

```
long timestamp;
...
if(new collision detected){
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

In this way your time will start from the moment you detect the collision and idx will always start from 0

---

EDIT

copy and paste this code, it's not tested but should work.

```
class FragileSquare{

FloatBuffer fVertexBuffer, mTextureBuffer;
ByteBuffer mColorBuff;
ByteBuffer mIndexBuff;
int[] textures = new int[1];
public boolean beingHitFromBall = false;
int numberSprites = 20;
int columnInt = 4;      //number of columns as int
float columnFloat = 4.0f; //number of columns as float
float rowFloat = 5.0f;
int oldIdx;

long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
lont time=0;

public FragileSquare() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    float vertices [] = {-1.0f,1.0f,            //byte index 0
                         1.0f, 1.0f,            //byte index 1
                                    //byte index 2
                         -1.0f, -1.0f,
                         1.0f,-1.0f};           //byte index 3


    float textureCoord[] = {
                            0.0f,0.0f,
                            0.25f,0.0f,
                            0.0f,0.20f,
                            0.25f,0.20f         


    };


    byte indices[] = {0, 1, 2,
            1, 2, 3 };

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*2 * 4); // 4 vertices, 2 co-ordinates(x,y) 4 for converting in float
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    fVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    fVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    fVertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 4);
    byteBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer =  byteBuffer2.asFloatBuffer();
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoord);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0);

}



public void draw(GL10 gl){
    long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp;
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(1,GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fVertexBuffer);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    if(MyRender.flag2==1){ /** Collision has taken place*/
        int idx = oldIdx==(numberSprites-1) ? (numberSprites-1) : (int)(((time+=delta)%(200*numberSprites))/200); 
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE); 
        gl.glTranslatef((idx%columnInt)/columnFloat, (idx/columnInt)/rowFloat, 0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
        oldIdx = idx;
    }else{
        time = 0;
    }



    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);



    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //4
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer); //5
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); //7

    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);


    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

}

public void loadFragileTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);


    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: The collision is being detected in the renderer class. So that means i have to include TWO STATIC data members, which i want to avoid.

Comment: Ok, I have two solutions. In your renderer class set flag2=System.currentTimeMillis() instead of 1 when there is a collision, 0 otherwise. In the draw function replace if(MyRender.flag2==1) with if(MyRender.flag2>0). MyRender.flag2 is now your timestamp and you are still using one static member.

Second idea, in your FragileSquare class add a member `long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();` and another one `int delta;` At the beginning of your draw method add `delta = System.currentTimeMillis(); timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: okay but Still System.currentTimeMillis() is there in...

int idx = oldIdx==(numberSprites-1) ? (numberSprites-1) : (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()%(200*numberSprites))/200);



So how should i overcome that?

In the SECOND IDEA : they both are the same Marco. Timestamp will be initialized as a class level member. and the same as in draw. SO what difference does it make? Please explain

Comment: delta is now the amount of milliseconds between each call to the draw method. In your `if(MyRender.flag2==1)` replace System.currentTimeMillis() with `t+=delta;` I forgot to tell you that you need to declare `int t;` near `int delta;` If you want to repeat the animation every time there is a collision you need to reset t to 0 when there is not a collision (example, add an else{ t=0; })

Comment: Sorry, I was adding another comment because of the characters limit. No in the 1st idea you neet to replace System.currentTimeMillis() with (System.currentTimeMillis()-MyRenderer.flag2)

Comment: Okay, but its all mixed up now.. i mean both the suggestions are mixed up, and now i am getting a blank expression after seeing t=0.

Comment: Ok I will try to explain it better, do you prefear to edit your Renderer class (easy) or only FragileSquare?

Comment: I'll prefer Fragile Square only :)

Comment: Ok I'm editing the answer

Comment: Did you tested my code?

Comment: Marco :  not now but i sure will because i am preoccupied with some stuff. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind, I've asked you just to know if it work or not. I'm curious ;)

Comment: Marco : I've tested the code and it works fine till now, sprites are not being skipped now. However, if I encounter any bugs, i'll intimate you.